# Angular 7, Cordova, console.log(cordova.plugins) isn't showing the plugin when running on android

Tags: android, typescript, cordova, angular7, cordova-plugins

--Solution for me: under platforms/android/platform_www/cordova_plugins.js i found the plugin, under its reference clobber, is how i should have been finding the plugin. So turns out i just needed to use the variable chooser (after device ready) instead of cordova.plugins

I have the cordova.js in the index.html file, 
If i call cordova plugins --list all the plugins show, including, in specific this one:
cordova-plugin-chooser 1.2.5 "Chooser",
which is the one I am wanting to use.
However when I ng build, then cordova run android, and start doing: 
console.log(cordova.plugins), it shows the plugin browsertab, permissions, but does not show chooser. 
Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Have you installed this plugin by running “cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chooser” ? Is there a reference to this plugin in your config.xml or your package.json ? If not, your plugin may not be installed.

Comment: Are you waiting for the “deviceready“ event before using this plugin ?

Comment: I have installed using cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-chooser, i am waiting for deviceready, it is in package.json under cordova{plugins